# Changing Bugzilla url

Tags: apache, bugzilla

I have installed Bugzilla with Apache on a Windows machine. The Bugzilla web application is set to http://localhost but i have to move it to http://localhost/bugzilla . I think that the Apache server must have a configuration file somewhere but i have little experience with it. Anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to reconfigure Apache, but here's how you would do it:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html

What you do need to change is the `urlbase` parameter that tells Bugzilla how to form links to other pages. Yours is probably set to `http://localhost/` at present; you probably want it to be `http://localhost/bugzilla/`.

See http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/parameters.html for what you can configure.

If you can't get Bugzilla to load at all, look for a file name `params.pl` and change the value of `urlbase` manually. You noramally s